# How to send form content with different subjects

Tags: jquery, forms

I need help with my contact formular on http://robert-richter.com under the navigation point Kontakt. I want to send this form with different subjects. Dependung on with option is selected in the drop down menu, I want to create an individual subject. The reason why I want to do this is because I want to use a filter in my email account wich saves emails based on the sibject title.

Example:

Contact Form Name: John Alex
Option Selected: Anfrage persönlich // german for private request

Subject in Mailbox: Persönliche Anfrage von Alex John 23/08/2013

Filter 'Persönliche Anfrage von' and save it in the folder 'Persönliche Anfragen' (eng: Private Requests)

```
<form title="Kontaktformular" name="subform" method="post" action="">
<label for="fname">Name</label>
<input name="name" title="Name" type="text">
<label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse</label>
<input name="email" title="Email" type="text">
<label for="auswahl">Präfix</label>

<label class="label">
    <select name="auswahl" class="dropdown">
    <option selected="" value="anfrage">Anfrage Webdesign</option>
    <option value="anfragep">Anfrage persönlich</option>
    <option value="andere">Alles andere</option>
    <option value="spam">Spam</option>
    </select>
</label>

<textarea name="text" title="Text" label="dwaa"></textarea>
<button value="send" type="submit" class="button">Absenden</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Which language are you using to process the form.

Comment: I was thinking about jquery. But everythings possible ;-)